# CMake compile options for libpng

Tags: cmake

I am using libpng in my project. Right now, I can compile my project with: g++ *.cpp `libpng-config --ldflags`

I want to switch to using CMake for easy recompiling but I don't know what to do for the libpng part. How do I provide `libpng-config --ldflags` with CMake?

Answer (score 18):

I finally solved it using `find_package`. Thanks to [this](https://fedetft.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/cmake-part-3-finding-libraries/) blog post.

```
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${MY_EXEC} ${PNG_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: ok, just remember that there are many libpng versions: libpng, libpng12, libpng14, libpng15, libpng16

Comment: This works for me momentarily. I'll try your solution when needed and thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Yes, this is the CMake way of doing it, +1. But then again, that's an answer to the question "How do I use libpng in my project with CMake?", which is technically *not* what you were asking about. So the original question was apparently an X-Y problem. I've edited it to reflect the true intent better.

Comment: Analogically it applies for TIFF as well.

Answer (score 8):

I think the recommended and **portable** way it should be done using pkg-config, something like this:

```
# search for pkg-config
include (FindPkgConfig)
if (NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    message (FATAL_ERROR "pkg-config not found")
endif ()

# check for libpng
pkg_check_modules (LIBPNG libpng16 REQUIRED)
if (NOT LIBPNG_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "You don't seem to have libpng16 development libraries installed")
else ()
    include_directories (${LIBPNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories (${LIBPNG_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    link_libraries (${LIBPNG_LIBRARIES})
endif ()
add_executable (app_png ${_MYSOURCES} ${LIBPNG_LINK_FLAGS})
```

Comment: +1. This is more appropriate solution. The non pkg-config solution will fail if host machine have libpng and libpng16 both and application dependency is on libpng16.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I don't know why people dont mark solutions.