# Force conda-installed executable to use the conda shared libraries at run time

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, libraries

I want to make the compilation and distribution of a C++ program portable and simple using `conda`, so I've written a conda recipe. The build depends on some libraries to deal with image I/O, for example `libpng` and `libtiff`. The `conda` versions of these libraries are specified in [the recipe](https://github.com/efmkoene/bm3d/blob/master/conda_recipe/meta.yaml), an excerpt is shown below:

```
requirements:
  run_exports:
    strong:
      - libpng
      - libtiff
      - jpeg
      - fftw
      - eigen
  host:
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    - cmake
    - python
    - libpng
    - libtiff
    - jpeg
    - fftw
    - eigen
  run:
    - libtiff
    - libpng
    - jpeg
    - fftw
```

my understanding is that `host` corresponds to the conda libraries used during compilation, while `run` and `run_exports` specify the libraries during runtime at the machine of the host or other machines.

On OS X, the [cmake](https://github.com/efmkoene/bm3d/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) compilation runs normally, and in particular successfully compiles against the conda versions of the image libraries. An excerpt of the installation as takes place within the `conda build .` operation is shown below:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 12.0.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: $PREFIX/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: $PREFIX/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp=libomp (found version "5.0") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp=libomp (found version "5.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "5.0")  
-- Found TIFF: $PREFIX/lib/libtiff.dylib (found version "4.0.9")  
-- Found JPEG: $PREFIX/lib/libjpeg.dylib (found version "80") 
-- Found ZLIB: $PREFIX/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: $PREFIX/lib/libpng.dylib (found version "1.4.12") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
    CMAKE_LIBTOOL


-- Build files have been written to: $SRC_DIR/build
Scanning dependencies of target bm3d
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bm3d.dir/bm3d.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/bm3d.dir/iio.c.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bm3d.dir/lib_transforms.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bm3d.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bm3d.dir/utilities.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bm3d
[100%] Built target bm3d
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bm3d
[100%] Built target bm3d
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: $PREFIX/bin/bm3d
```

At the end of the conda building process, I then upload the package to the `anaconda` store, and install it (`conda install -c efmkoene bm3d`). But then upon testing, it turns out the executable is using a different set of libraries for the image I/O -- in my case causing trouble. An example of the program run against an image (e.g., `bm3d ~/Downloads/example.png 10 out.png`) gives

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.4.12 but running with 1.6.37

ERROR(""): png_create_read_struct fail
```

Note thus how the `libpng` on runtime (in this case, a result of `brew install libpng`) is not the same as the one used for the compilation, even though I am in the same runtime environment as the one used for the compilation. Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523911/osx-homebrew-cmake-libpng-version-mismatch-issue which says that the claim during build time of using the libpng library version 4.x may actually be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the error was indeed in the `cmake` process detecting wrong info regarding `libpng`. Adding `set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK LAST)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` fixed the issue! As reported at [OSX + homebrew + CMake + libpng version mismatch issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523911/osx-homebrew-cmake-libpng-version-mismatch-issue) by Kikaxa:

> The problem is that classical cmake-style Find*.cmake search for the
> headers and libraries separately - and the results MAY and WILL
> mismatch in some cases. MacOS exaggerates the problem by having
> special case of frameworks, being searched BEFORE other locations by
> default.