# cmake: find_package for architecture

Tags: c++, cmake

When cross-compiling, I am in the habit of using a toolchain file to specify (among other things) the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`.

In Ubuntu and other Linux distros, it seems to be able to install libraries intended for other architectures. For example, if I am working on an x86-64 machine, and want to install `libpng` for 64-bit ARM, then I would:

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt-get update
apt-get -y install libpng-dev:arm64
```

So after this, I have the libpng binaries for arm64. These seem to be installed in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`.

Now my understanding is that if I try to find the `libpng` in my CMakeLists.txt file (see [CMake compile options for libpng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980383/cmake-compile-options-for-libpng)):

```
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(example ${PNG_LIBRARY})
```

it will find the packages for the host machine (in this case x86-64), and not the target (arm64).

Is there a way to tell Cmake's `find_package` the target architecture? In the ideal case, `find_package` would examine `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` before searching. I would like to know the easiest and most general way to handle this scenario since I am linking several libraries.

Right now the only method I am aware of is to hardcode the paths to the target libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules like [FindPNG.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPNG.cmake#L79) use `find_path` and `find_library` to find all the things.

You can influence [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) by setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` to `aarch64-linux-gnu`. Try just setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` in your toolchain file.