# Runtime error when running libpng application

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile openGL file including "png.h" header file,

I got the following error:

```
Open GL version 2.1 ATI-3.2.24
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.4.12 but running with 1.6.37
error: png_create_read_struct returned 0.
Failed to read image texture from ../images/ceramic.png
```

My Cmakelists.txt file :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
project (teapot)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(teapot teapot.cpp)

target_link_libraries(teapot ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}  ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${PNG_LIBRARIES} )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


if (APPLE)
  set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wno-deprecated-declarations ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif ()

set_target_properties(teapot PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)
```

cmake . works fine, but when I execute ./teapot the above error occurred. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `../images/ceramic.png` used for? Are you sure this relative path is valid?

Comment: It is the path of my png file I want to read from, and I am sure it is a valid path

Comment: Can you inspect the contents of `${PNG_LIBRARIES}`? I'm pretty sure it will contain a `-L` argument that points to a directory containing a `libpng.dylib` different than the one reported by `otool -L teapot`

Comment: You mind if I ask how can I inspect the contents of ${PNG_LIBRARIES}?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably only have development libraries installed for `libpng-1.4.12` and not for `libpng-1.6.37` or some other "non-standard" installation.

But the message seems pretty clear you linked against an older version but have a newer version in the runtime path of loadable libraries.

`find_package(PNG REQUIRED)` is only going to search the "standard" locations via `find_library()`.

You may also want to update your `CMakeLists.txt` file to use `target_link_libraries( ... PNG::PNG)`.  This is simpler than trying to use the `PNG` variables that get set; which is missing `PNG_DEFINITIONS` when compiling your project.  Refer to the CMake manual `buildsystem` section about library targets.

You can inspect the variables by using the `message()` command to print out their values.  Some of them will also be stored in `CMakeCache.txt`.

If `libpng` isn't in the standard locations then you have to use `target_link_libraries( ... /path/to/lib)` and `target_include_directories( ... /path/to/lib/headers)`, etcetera to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, `/usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib/usr/lib/libz.dylib` this is what I got for message(${PNG_LIBRARIES}). And I have tried to add `PNG:PNG`, but gives me this: `ld: library not found for -lPNG:PNG`

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS. So you are linking against libpng and libz.  The output will make more sense if you use `message(PNG_LIBRARIES="${PNG_LIBRARIES}")`; then it will appear as a list of libraries to link against. There's a typo in my answer, it's `PNG::PNG`. The documentation should clarify it.

Comment: It seems like after using `PNG::PNG`, it still gives me the same error, and the message gives me this `PNG_LIBRARIES="/usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib/usr/lib/libz.dylib"`

Comment: Your problem isn't necessarily with `CMake`.  The problem also appears to be with your `libpng` installation. I was just also commenting on your `CMake` files to fix some additional issues.  You need to fix why there is both libpng 1.4.12 and 1.6.37 installed.  Did you install the 1.6.37 development libraries?  Are they located in the default locations for MacOS? If you don't install it in the correct location then you have to follow the documentation for `CMake` on how to tell let `find_library()` know where you did install it for it to link against it if that is the version you want to use.

Comment: I went to /usr/local/Cellar/libpng, it only shows one folder as 1.6.37, is there anyway I can select which version of libpng to be built with?

Comment: Not that I know of by using `find_package`.  You can look at the `CMake` file `FindPNG.cmake` on how it sets up the import target and use the correct directory values.  But you don't have to use the `import target` method.  You can simple link against the library.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I finally solved it regarding to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981965/9016099 in case you want to know it.